# 403::Unknown client - error in cometd subscription response

Tags: cometd

Im getting a 403::Unknown client error in the response for my subscription request.
I handshake no problem. Then i use the clientId from the handshake response in my subscription request but i get that error in the response then.

My handshake request is:

```
"version":                  "1.0",
"minimumVersion":           "1.0",
"channel":                  "/meta/handshake",
"supportedConnectionTypes": []string{"long-polling"},
```

My handshake response:

```
Successful:true
Channel:"/meta/handshake"
Error:""
ClientId:"abcd"
```

Then my subscription request is

```
"channel":      "/meta/subscribe",
"subscription": "/data/ChangeEvents",
"clientId":     "abcd",
```

My subscription response

```
Successful:false
Channel:"/meta/subscribe"
Error:"403::Unknown client"
ClientId:""
Subscription:""
```

I dont know why its saying the client is unknown if im using the one from the handshake. I have no other cometd processes running, since im running this in a go project and connecting to salesforce in there. Nor is it a long lived connection. its a brand new connection i just did the handshake right before it

Comment: Your client could be doing lots of things that Salesforce doesn't like. See linked article for likely culprit and see [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236645/cannot-subscribe-to-platform-events-using-cometd) for good advice on how to troubleshoot.

Comment: That workaround doesnt look like it will help my problem, Im already connecting using the instance URL, so na11.salesforce.com/cometd/52.0. I dont need the connect or anything at the end it should be the channel that handles where it goes.

Comment: @identigral I dont see anything in there that could be causing my issue. My subscribe is only called after the handshake is returned. The authorization works fine for the handshake and so doesnt ever log out before i subscribe. The subscription seems correct, as per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_channels.htm

Comment: I added the Advice and in there it has "advice":"reconnect":"handshake"}, which apparently means it needs to do the handshake again, but why I just did it

Comment: Might be timing-related between handshake and subscribe along these lines: https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues/775 . 403 is a generic error message. If you feel that you're doing everything correctly, there are no other connections by the same client and your network path from client to Salesforce is rock-solid, then it's time to open a support case with SF.

Answer (score 0):

when you send the `connect` or `subscribe` request, you MUST to put cookies into http header you received in the http header of the `handshake` respond.
[according to third requirement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_client_specs.htm)